# Where can I get printed crown caps?

Tags: caps, printing

I'm investigating buying crown caps in bulk and having a logo and/or my name professionally printed on them.

Does anyone know if this is possible on a small-ish scale and is it within the budget of a home-brewer?

Who does this kind of printing? Does anyone have a website or contact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wild Hops does laser etched caps- http://www.wildhopsprintshop.com/store/custom-bottle-caps.html

You can also get a pretty good look by printing on 1" round labels-
http://www.homebrewfinds.com/2010/12/labeling-your-homebrew-part-2.html

Comment: That's exactly what I was after - thanks for the links! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a few years but if you're still looking, I order my caps from https://www.blankmediaprinting.com/Custom-Bottle-Caps