# Where can I get custom crown caps in the UK?

Tags: capping, caps

I've been looking around trying to find anywhere that can print low-volume (50-100) runs of custom crown caps.  Found loads of US sites but nothing in the UK.  Any ideas?

Cheers!

(Related to [this](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/where-can-i-get-printed-crown-caps) question but specifically for the UK)

Comment: Hmmm. @baka Kind of disagree with closing this question. The UK is hardly a 'small geographic area', particularly with regards to brewing. The number of upvotes shows interest in good answers. How would you write such a question for something that requires a localised response?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the various flags on a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a UK company starting up that says they're going to do this. They haven't started yet so i can't speak for their quality but probably worth a look because at the very least it would save you on shipping. They're called Your Brew (www.YourBrew.co.uk).

They had an offer on to sign up for free samples when they finally open (which i signed up for) but haven't received any yet. Might be one to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you've already seen the US-based [Bottlemark](http://www.bottlemark.com/), out of Houston, Texas. If you can't find a low-volume cap customizer in the UK, I would say that Bottlemark is your next-best bet. Shipping on 100 caps is estimated to be just [USD$10 internationally](http://www.bottlemark.com/info/shipping).

Comment: Cheers mattozan.  That certainly looks promising and reasonably priced.  I'll have a proper look and accept as an answer if it works!

Comment: I already gave my +1, but I just got an order I placed with Bottlemark. I can say the caps are excellent. The only things to keep in mind is that their caps are a white base, so the sides will be white. That, and order a few extra. I had a misprint or two in a bad of 70. Just slight things, but if you want them perfect, it won't hurt, since they're just $.12 each.

Comment: Delayed reply, but finally got around to ordering.  Website very good and easy.  Got 300 caps made in 8 different designs, total cost was $55.76.  Didn't get charged by customs/Royal Mail either luckily, although have been on similarly priced items (would have been VAT + £8 = extra ~£15).  Approx 2 week from order to delivery and look pretty good.  Total cost ~11.9p per cap.  Will def use again unless I can find comparable UK service.

Answer (score 1):

i was also looking for a company that printed bottle tops in the uk and tried www.YourBrew.co.uk ,, I was very very impressed and now use them for all my requirements.

Answer (score -1):

www.yourbrew.co.uk is the best i have found in Europe for the moment. Free delivery over 35 pounds in all countries.